# can exact target connect to a 3rd party web service?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, wsdl

Can exacttarget be configured to connect to a 3rd party webservice returning a JSON object?

I guess there are two questions:
- can I cause exacttarget to connect to a 3rd party webservice to populate an email body with info? (exact target would initiate the connection and make the request)
- if so, can exact target parse a returned JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the web service itself and how the connection is initiated, but you can probably use HttpGET() to get the JSON, then parse it using SSJS.

See this question: [Can AMPScript parse JSON?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/can-ampscript-parse-json)

If you post more info on the API and how the connection works we might be able to give you a better example.

Comment: I didn't realized you replied, thank you!  Here is an example of the request: http://www.someurl.com/get_latest_info/today and this would return a json object with some basic data.  Really simple stuff.  I'll take a look at the link you sent over.  Thanks again