# How can we get JSON data from a POST request in landing pages in salseforce in AMP script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to integrate Webhook(sending data in JSON format) to  salseforce exacttarget , so want to know how to handle it in amp script.

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific functions in AMPScript to parse JSON objects.

You'll need to utilizes SFMC's [**Server-Side JavaScript**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) or [**GTL**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/).

Comment: Thanks Adam for your input , It would be great if you can provide some information on how to receive data/payload from external REST POST request in exacttarget landing page ?

Comment: Examples of both here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/can-ampscript-parse-json