# Generating Salesforce OAuth2 token via SSJS returning empty response

Tags: marketing-cloud, oauth2, html, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to generate OAuth2 SF token via SSJS code on a CloudPage. I am not sure why I receive an empty response here. Following is my code

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1");

try {
  var instanceUrl = 'https://XXXXX--sandbox1.my.salesforce.com';
  var url = instanceUrl + '/services/oauth2/token'
  var payload = {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: 'My Client ID',
      client_secret: 'My Client Secret',
      username: 'Username',
      password: 'Password'
    };
  var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  request.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  request.continueOnError = true;
  request.method = 'POST';
  request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  request.postData = Stringify(payload);      

  var response = request.send();
  Platform.Response.Write("</br> response: " + String(response.content));
  var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(response.content));
  Platform.Response.Write("</br> resultJSON: " + resultJSON);


} catch (ex) {
    Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}

</script>
```

Following is the response printed when I click on Schedule/Publish:

```
response:
resultJSON: null
```

I use the same credentials via POSTMAN and I am able to generate the token successfully. So I am not sure why I receive an empty response here. Would great if someone can point me in the right direction.

ANSWER

Thanks to the following post: [Getting Error while try to get Salesforce OAuth access token from SFMC cloudpages ssjs httppost?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225892/getting-error-while-try-to-get-salesforce-oauth-access-token-from-sfmc-cloudpage), I have tried the HTTPPost AMPScript function and it worked. Following is the modified code and it works:

```
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");

    try {  
      var clientId = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
      var clientSecret = 'MY_CLIENT_SEC';
      var username = 'USERNAME';
      var password = 'PASSWORD'; 

      var payload = 'grant_type=password&client_id=';
      payload +=clientId;
      payload +='&client_secret=';
      payload +=clientSecret;
      payload +='&username=';
      payload +=username;
      payload +='&password=';
      payload +=password;

      Variable.SetValue('@payload', payload);

      Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%%[ HTTPPost("https://pmisa--sandbox1.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @payload, @response) ]%%');

      var response = Variable.GetValue('@response');    
      response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response);
      Write("</br> access_token: " + (response['access_token']));

    } catch (e) {

      Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));

    }

</script>
```

Comment: `response.content` (et al.) might still be an `object` (you can verify using the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)) and would therefore require a type conversion before it can be printed out, e.g., `Platform.Response.Write("</br> response: " + String(response.content));`. Or maybe `Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(response.content));`.

Comment: Thank you  @MarkG , Please find the updates in the question desrcipton with the tests you suggested. Everything shows up as _null_

Comment: What does `Platform.Response.Write(typeof response.content);` return?

Comment: @MarkG `Platform.Response.Write(typeof response.content);` returns `clr`

Comment: What about `Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(response.content));`, what does that return?

Comment: `Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(response.content));` returns `""`

Comment: I was able to get the token succsefully by using `HTTPPost` AMPSCript function. I have no clue why `Script.Util.HttpRequest` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things to note:

1) you do not need to load the platform core twice in one cloudpage.

2) You can use `Write("test")` instead of `Platform.Response.Write("test")`

3) use TreatAsContent to get rid of the extra script tags (watch out for wrapping or escaping quotes correctly!):

```js
Variable.SetValue('@payload', payload);
Platform.Function.TreatAsContent("%%[ HTTPPost('https://XXXX--sandbox1.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token','application/x-www-form-urlencoded', @payload, @response) ]%%");
var response = Variable.GetValue('@response');
```